# JSON Object cannot be cast to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, nativescript

Im using this code as metadata for nativescript vue raddataform if it matters in this case.

I want to make my code more my range validator in variable to use it multitimes. but I got this error.

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
```

So what should I do to make it working?

```
export default {
  data () {
      return {
        val: {

            'name': 'RangeValidator',
            'params': {
              'minimum': 1,
              'maximum': 15,
              'errorMessage': 'Value must be between 1-15.',
            }

        },
        makeRuneMetadata: {
          'isReadOnly': false,
          'commitMode': 'OnLostFocus',
          'validationMode': 'Immediate',
          'propertyAnnotations':
          [ 
            {
              'name': 'r_makeRuneSpell',
              'displayName': 'Make rune spell',
              'index': 0,
              'editor': 'Text',
            },
            {
              'name': 'r_mpAbove',
              'displayName': 'If MP above [%]',
              'index': 1,
              'editor': 'Number',
              'validators': [ this.val ] // <-----------------
            },
          [
         }
    }
}
```

**EDITED**
i made file validator.js

```
 const val1090 = {

            'name': 'RangeValidator',
            'params': {
                'minimum': 10,
                'maximum': 90,
                'errorMessage': 'Value must be between 10-90.'
            }  

};

const val115 = {

    'name': 'RangeValidator',
    'params': {
      'minimum': 1,
      'maximum': 15,
      'errorMessage': 'Value must be between 1-15.'
    }  

};

export default { val1090 }
```

And I imported this and console log like this

```
import val1090 from "./validator";

export default {
  created(){
    console.dir(val1090);
```

and it gives me an output

```
 ==== object dump start ====
JS: val1090: {
JS:   "name": "RangeValidator",
JS:   "params": {
JS:     "minimum": 10,
JS:     "maximum": 90,
JS:     "errorMessage": "Value must be between 10-90."
JS:   }
JS: }
JS: ==== object dump end ====
```

How to got only what this object contains ? without - JS: val1090: {

Comment: That error message looks like it's from Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar in nativescript, sometimes, the native error is shown when an exception occurs on the native level and can actually be detected. I'm not a Vue.js dragon, but `[ this.val ]` may act weird due to the "this".

Comment: I dont think you can do what youre trying to do, atleast not in the way you are trying to do it. perhaps store the `val` property in a separate file or class or something?

Comment: Try to use some JSON validator to check if data has in correct format.
I think you should check quotes (double/single)

Comment: Can you share a Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced?